# How to connect Android Application to Internet when the screen is locked?

Tags: android

After some research on Google Search, I tried to find a solution to connect my Android Application to internet when the screen is locked and without the phone charging.

My first impression is that the phone block in background my application. Strange things because others applications on Google Play Store can communicate on the Internet and do things on background.

I have already tried to search solutions on the Internet. My search apparently turn to this link to keep the device awake:

https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock

But this solution did not work properly for me and the android system block my application in background when the screen is locked. If the screen is unlocked, the application works properly.

Moreover, I do not understand the problem. Probably, the android energy saver block my application.

Have you any idea to fix this? And if not, how to use the wakeLock?

Thank you :)

Comment: post your code where yo implemented network call

Comment: you using services ?

Comment: Yes, I use ServiceManager and BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Show your code so i can see where it's going wrong

Comment: The Service works properly when the screen is unlock. What is the process to make service enable when the screen is locked ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: well it's obvious that you need wake lock ...you don't need permanent wake lock...you can do like have wake lock for some time then after task complete you can release wake lock

Comment: i posted a answer with ways to have wake lock...see i this can solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is two way to hold the CPU running (on) even after screen lock

**1. Wake Lock**

wake lock hold cpu on as long as you acquire it. for acquiring wakelock

first define this permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

then you can have wakelock like this

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

and after your task is done you can release wakelock like this

```
wakeLock.release();
```

**UPDATE**

> WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated now with android 8.0

**2. WakefulBroadcastReceiver**

it's a special broadcast receiver that takes care everything about wakelock

for using this first define in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".WakefulReceiver"/>
```

and then same as we use our service you can do

```
public class WakefulReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        startWakefulService(context, your_service_intent);
    }
}
```

here you can see all we have to do is start service using startWakefulService
this will take care everything

Comment: Thank you but the method called "WakefulBroadcastReceiver" is deprecated since the version 25.

Comment: wait let me check that